# Xpath how to select an element based on an order and dependent of its existence

Tags: xml, xpath

how to select an element based on an order and dependent of its existence in XPath ?
For example how to select the best quality video if it exist.

```
<VIDEOS>
    <LOW_RES>video_L.flv</LOW_RES>
    <HI_RES>video_H.flv</HI_RES>
    <HD/>
</VIDEOS>
```

this should return video_H.flv because the hd version doesn't exist

this case can exist (the videos names can be random):

```
<VIDEOS>
    <LOW_RES>video_L.flv</LOW_RES>
    <HI_RES>video_H.flv</HI_RES>
    <HD>video_hd.mp4</HD>
</VIDEOS>
```

this should return video_hd.mp4 because the hd version exist.
Many thanks.

Comment: aren't you just looking for the last child element of VIDEOS that has text?

Comment: Good Question (+1). See my answer for a complete XPath-only solution. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use**:

```
/*/HD[text()]
|
 /*/HI_RES[text() and not(../HD/text())]
|
 /*/LOW_RES[text() and not(../HD/text()) and not(../HI_RES/text())]
```